# What's the best action to use when you want to do something only once per theme setup?

Tags: theme-development, actions, customization

I'm writing a theme which has it's own set of database tables.
I'm wondering what is the best action for me to use when I want my install function to be invoked only once when the theme is activated for the first time?

I know there is a `setup_theme` action, but not sure if that's the one I should use.

Comment: I think `setup_theme` is run on every page views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read this: [Activation/Deactivation hook for wordpress theme](http://www.krishnakantsharma.com/2011/01/activationdeactivation-hook-for-wordpress-theme/)

Comment: Lone link is [considered a poor answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion) since it is meaningless by itself and target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future. Please try to include at least summary of information you are linking to.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try, since it's an SQL issue, using `IF NOT EXISTS` in your query to ensure that it doesn't run twice.